# Automate file joining/merging in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, merge

I have a largish number of data files that need to be joined in the following way.

**Step 1.**

The data need to be joined within 'locations', which are annoyingly split in two parts (Part A and Part B). The files are stored in one folder, with random, unsequential location numbers, e.g.:

```
PartA_location012843.csv
PartB_location012843.csv
PartA_location465475.csv
PartB_location465475.csv
...
```

Is there a way to loop through all files, joining parts A and B within each location, without manually specifying location id numbers?
The join would then be a simple `left_join(PartA_locationX, PartB_locationX, by='common_field')` from `dplyr`. I am guessing the output would be a series of data-frame objects in R's working space, one for each location:

```
location012843
location465475
...
```

**Step 2.**

Next, all locations need to be appended together to one data-frame with `rjoin`, keeping location_id, such that:

```
     location_id fieldA fieldB common_field
1 location012843      x      y            c
2 location012843      x      y            c
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give a ton of details so this code assumes that you have two CSVs for each location and no missing CSV files. It also assumes all location codes are exactly six digits. This creates a single `data.frame` for all of the locations as you specified at the end of Step 2 and skips creating data frames for each location separately as you mentioned in Step 1 - if you need those you could `filter` them out later.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# Create list of CSV files to pull in
a_files <- list.files("your_folder/", pattern = "PartA")
b_files <- list.files("your_folder/", pattern = "PartB")

# Create df for final output
final_df < - data.frame()

for (i in seq_along(a_files)) {

  # Extract location name from PartA file name
  loc_a <- str_extract(a_files[i], "location[0-9]{6}")

  # Read in CSVs and store location as variable
  parta <- read.csv(a_files[i]) %>%
    mutate(location_id = str_extract(a_files[i], "location[0-9]{6}"))
  partb <- read.csv(b_files[i]) %>%
    mutate(location_id = str_extract(b_files[i], "location[0-9]{6}"))

  # Join on common field and location 
  # Will throw errors if the locations are off in parta and partb
  final_df <- left_join(parta, partb, by= c('common_field', 'location_id')) %>%
    bind_rows(final_df)

}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works well up to `bind_rows`. Instead of binding all values in `field_A` and `field_B` together, it creates additional `field_A.x` and `field_B.x` and fills combinations with NAs.

Comment: Are both `field_A` and `field_B` in the `PartA` and `PartB` files? If so, you probably want to drop the `field_B` variable from the `PartA` dataset and vice versa

Comment: No, `field_A` is only in `PartA` and `field_B` is only in `PartB`. I could share the dummy files I am playing with if I knew how.

Comment: can you `dput()` some of what is being generated in the `parta` and `partb` dataframes? `dplyr` adds the `.x` and `.y` to clarify things when joining tbls with the same variable in them, which suggests that they're sharing column names....

Comment: Actually, just looked at the earlier output you gave - looks like in location312523 you have field_A in both CSVs, while in location012345 things merged correctly. This is likely an issue with your CSVs for that location

Comment: thank you, it was indeed a slip on my part. It now works perfectly! I am lucky location_ids are always 6 digits long! Otherwise it would have been more tricky.